# How to display Images from Internet in JavaFX(not working)?

Tags: java, json, url, javafx, imageview

I want to take the url of a image from a API, which I did. I also get the URL of the image that I want, but the image doesn't display in the JavaFX Scene.

```
String json2=readUrl("https://imsea.herokuapp.com/api/1?q=moon");
images.Images i=gson.fromJson(json2,images.Images.class);
System.out.println(i.getResult1());
String path = i.getResult1();
Image image = new Image(new FileInputStream(i.getResult1()));
img_spaceObject.setImage(image);
```

*Update: I did that by first downloading the image and then displaying it, but I wanted a short version, as I mentioned before.

Comment: I don't know [tag:json], but you can construct an [`Image`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/Image.html) with a URL of type `String`.

Comment: What is the output from the last `System.out.println(…)`?

Comment: Don't use a `FileInputStream`, just pass the url you need directly to the Image constructor.  I know json, but I don't know gson, so can't advise on the rest of your code.

Comment: @James_D Output:https://tse2.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.wNDH2qSu6oOl48-p3c9wkQHaGL&amp for ex.

Comment: I asked what the output from the `System.out.println(…)` statement was. What is the value of `path`?

Comment: The value of path is the image URL.

Comment: So why don’t you just do `Image image = new Image(path);`?

Answer (score -1):

To quote [the Javadoc](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/Image.html):

```
Image image3 = new Image("http://sample.com/res/flower.png", 100, 0, false, false);
```

Just pass your desired URL to the constructor.